# Solvable Lie algebra whose nilradical is not characteristic

Tags: lie-algebras, modular-lie-algebras

Say that an ideal in a Lie algebra is *characteristic* if it is invariant under every derivation of the algebra.

> It is well known that the nilradical of a finite-dimensional Lie algebra over a field of characteristic $p > 0$ need not be characteristic, but is there an example of a **solvable** finite-dimensional Lie algebra with non-characteristic nilradical?

It is clear that the nilradical is invariant under automorphisms (this is also sometimes used a a definition of characteristic ideal). For an ideal in a finite-dimensional Lie algebra in characteristic zero, the latter is equivalent to being characteristic. But this is not the case in positive characteristic.

([Cross-posted from MathSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681412/solvable-lie-algebra-with-non-characteristic-nilradical))

Comment: @ Y Cor: By 'characteristic' I mean invariant under all derivations of the algebra. I do only have finite-dimensional Lie algebras in mind. In the non-solvable case there is an example given by Seligman in http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1957-008-01/S0002-9939-1957-0082974-9/S0002-9939-1957-0082974-9.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Google "characteristic ideal" first points to http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Characteristic_ideal_of_a_Lie_ring which defines it as an ideal stable under automorphisms, which is indeed a distinct definition.

Comment: @Y Cor Yes, I thought you were thinking about stability under automorphisms. In characteristic zero, stability under all automorphisms implies stability under all derivations, but that breaks down in characteristic p > 0.

Comment: By a result of Maksimenko, such an example would need a nilradical of nilpotency class greater than or equal to p-1, where p is the characteristic of the underlying field. So such an example may be easiest to construct over a field of small characteristic.

Comment: Cross-posted to MathSE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681412/

Answer (score 1):

The question was somewhat answered by the OP in comments of the [MathSE duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681412/), so let me copy the relevant parts here for the record:

*Did you test all low-dimensional solvable Lie algebras in characteristic , classified by Willem de Graaf [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0404071), for small , e.g., for =2 or =3 ?* – Dietrich Burde Mar 3 '16

*I've had a look at these, but there are none amongst the 3-dimensional algebras. I haven't yet examined all of the 4-dimensional ones (...).* – David Towers Mar 3 '16

*I have found a 4-dimensional example over $\mathrm{GF}(2)$.* – David Towers Mar 7 '16

---

Feel free to edit this cw answer if you indeed identify the 4-dimensional solvable Lie algebra over a field of characteristic $2$ that works.

Comment: PS: it would be certainly interesting too to know whether there are examples in arbitrary finite characteristic $p$. (As mentioned in a comment, the nilpotency class of the nilradical should be $\ge p-1$. The mentioned Maksimenko reference can be found [here](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=adm&paperid=109&option_lang=eng): Dmitriy V. Maksimenko, On action of outer derivations on nilpotent
ideals of Lie algebras, Algebra Discrete Math., 2009, Issue 1, 74-82.)